# jquery-queryBuilder init rules with last search submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-query-builder

I have a form with integrated the plugin `querybuilder.js.org`

My **`js`** is:

FROM: **`scripts.js`**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

 // INIT PLUGIN

 $('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder({
   plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'],
   filters: [{
     id: 'description',
     label: 'Description',
     type: 'string'
   }]
 });

 // RESTORE RULES FROM LAST SEARCH

 $('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('setRules', decodeURIComponent($("#rules").val()) );

 // ON SUBMIT, EDIT THE FORM AND APPEND SQL, PARAMS to USE IN SEARCH FROM DATABASE, AND APPEND RULES TO RESTORE IT TO NEXT LOAD OF THE PAGE

 $("#btn-submit").on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    var form = $("#form");  
    var rules = $('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('getRules');
    var query = $('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('getSQL', 'question_mark');

    // FOR RESTORE INITIAL VALUES ON RELOAD PAGE            
    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="rules" value="' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(rules, null, 2)) + '">');

    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="sql" value="' + query.sql + '">');

    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="params" value="' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(query.params, null, 2)) + '">');

    form.submit();

 });

});
```

My piece of code in **`index.php`** is:

```
<?php

  if ( isset($_POST) ) {

  $rules = isset($_POST['rules']) ? $_POST['rules'] : "";

  }

  ?>

  <form name="form" id="form" role="form" method="post" action="">
    <div id="queryBuilder"></div>

    <!--used only to restore rules in jquery-querybuilder-->
    <input type="hidden" id="rules" value="<?php echo $rules; ?>">


    <button type="button" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
  </form>
```

Problem is that rules are not restored as expected.

If I insert an alert on document ready **like**:

```
alert(decodeURIComponent($("#rules").val()));
```

I get **correct rules**:

```
{
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "description",
      "field": "description",
      "type": "string",
      "input": "text",
      "operator": "equal",
      "value": "test value"
    }
  ],
  "valid": true
}
```

It seem this `$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('setRules', decodeURIComponent($("#rules").val()) );` is not a valid way to init the plugin.

If I try to **hard-code** the rules in this way:

```
var rules_basic = {
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "description",
      "field": "description",
      "type": "string",
      "input": "text",
      "operator": "equal",
      "value": "test value"
    }
  ],
  "valid": true
};

$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder({
   plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'],
   filters: [{
     id: 'description',
     label: 'Description',
     type: 'string'
   }],
   rules: rules_basic 
 });
```

Then all work correctly!

How can I force to get init rules from an dynamic hidden input field? My `script.js` is separate from HTML so i can't (and I don't want) to force writing initial rules using `PHP` like:

**`index.php`**:

```
.... HTML PART

..... JS PART

$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder({
   plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'],
   filters: [{
     id: 'description',
     label: 'Description',
     type: 'string'
   }],
   rules: <?php echo $rules; ?>    // <---------------- HERE
 });
```

Comment: Possible reason is that you got a string value with ".val" function but plugin needs an JSON object to set the rules, please try to use this code:
var customRules = decodeURIComponent($("#rules").val());
$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('setRules', JSON.parse(customRules) );

Comment: You may also need to filter your input for possible XSS attack `$rules = isset($_POST['rules']) ? $_POST['rules'] : "";`

Comment: @AzharRasheed yes i've already do it. I simplified my code here to save time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reason is that you got a string value with ".val" function but plugin needs an JSON object to set the rules, please try to use this code in script.js:

```
var customRules = decodeURIComponent($("#rules").val());
$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('setRules', JSON.parse(customRules) );
```

Instead of this one:

```
$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder('setRules', decodeURIComponent($("#rules").val()) );
```